# Is there a way to combine object lib and .mod files into a single file reference Intel Fortran

Tags: visual-studio, fortran, static-libraries, intel-fortran

I'm using Intel Visual Fortran (Intel 2017 and Visual Studio 2015).

Currently my static library projects create, a single `.lib` and several `.obj` and `.mod` files. To use in another project I have to have the new project link to a folder containing the `.lib` file and all of the `.mod` files. Is there some method to wrap all of that up into a single file, to make sharing the finished library easier?

Comment: Unfortunately the answer with a comment was removed, now trying to reproduce the comment. As far as I understand the question is about the placing the `.mod`  files in one file (preferably with the `lib` file). OP has already placed all objects in the `lib` file. Merging `.mod` files is, to the best of my knowledge, not possible. The only possibility I see is to pack all the `.mod` files into a zip / tar file (can also include the `lib`) and distribute  this packed file and have the 'user' unzip / untar this packed file.

Comment: That's what I figured. That's frustrating.